# Does Drupal Disqus Commenting have a Server Side rending for SEO indexing?

Tags: 7, comments

Having to outsource the commenting service to disqus saves alot of time, but is there a way to have these Disqus comments rendered on the server side before displaying it to the end user? My main concern is for SEO indexing. What solutions are there to keep the SEO indexing in tact when using Disqus commenting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disqus itself does support this (see [this post](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472125-data-synchronization-for-local-storage) for example) but I do not believe that the [Disqus Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/disqus) supports this. It would probably be a worthwhile contribution to that module (or perhaps a companion module).